# Apache Superset Rest API: How do I get chart screenshot

Tags: rest, apache-superset

I want to call following api to get screenshot of chart from superset.

/api/v1/chart/{pk}/screenshot/{digest}

But I don't know what should I input to {digest}.

Can someone please tell me what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method /api/v1/chart/{pk}/cache_screenshot/ to get the key.
cache_key from response this method and there is digest

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If I had to guess, you want to use the method you suggested, then get a response from that and input that to `digest`.  Essentially, I don't understand your answer based on how you have phrased it.

Comment: You got it right. To get the digest, you need to call my method and substitute the value from the response in the digest.